# Hide Row when other Toggled - Wordpress Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, toggle, rows

I am trying to show/hide rows on WpBakery when an image is clicked. When the first image is clicked I would like a row to toggle. When the second image is clicked I would like first row to hide and then the second row to show. I would like to do this with 10 different images. I have adapted the following code which I found online:

add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { ?>

```
<script>

    ( function( $ ) {

        'use strict';

        $( document ).ready( function() {

            var $trigger = $( '.open-stan' );

            var $hiddenRow = $( '.stan' );

            var $trigger1 = $( '.open-test' );

            var $hiddenRow1 = $( '.test' );


            if ( $hiddenRow.length ) {
                $trigger.click( function() {
                    $hiddenRow.toggle();
                    $hiddenRow1.hide();

                    return false;           
                } );
                    }

            else if ( $hiddenRow1.length ) {
                $trigger1.click( function() {
                    $hiddenRow1.toggle();
                    $hiddenRow.hide();

                    return false;           
                } );
                    }

        } );

    } ( jQuery ) );

</script>
```

To test if it is working hiddenRow1 is shown when I open the page as I have not hidden it using CSS, if you click on the first image (trigger) this hides hiddenRow1 and displays hiddenRow. However when you click on the second image nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use similar like this...

```html
$(".row_class").click(function(){
   $(".row_class").not(this).removeClass('show');
   $(this).addClass('show');
});
```